# What is the driest, brownest bread that I can make for a stuffing?

Tags: bread, stuffing

I once had someone's Wonderbread stuffing (not good), and I decided that when it came time for me to make my own stuffing, I would go the exact opposite route.

I am going to make a loaf of bread in my bread machine with the intent to turn it into a stuffing. Thus I want an extremely brown, super multi-whole-grain, and dry bread that will not crumble apart. I do not care if the bread has a strong taste, but it should go well with Rosemary-Sage and Sausage.

My German Cousin tells me that German Pumpernickel tends to crumble, so I am going to exclude that before hand. Russian Black bread was also suggested; does that hold its form well?

Comment: It doesn't get much darker than Russian black bread: http://allrecipes.com/recipe/7034/russian-black-bread/ you can dry it yourself in a low oven. I wouldn't use it entirely, another bread with nuts and seeds and whole grains would be good with it.

Comment: Cube it first, and then put it in a ~175F oven until it is good and dry, but not toasted. Do the same with your companion whole-grain but lighter in color bread.

Comment: I think a stuffing made just of the black bread would be too dark and too dense. I would go no more than one third of that, and two thirds of something else. The something else could be chock-full of nuts and seeds and whole grains. They would complement each other quite well I think. Once you acknowledge this comment, I'm going to delete them all. Join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan) anytime. This is just the kind of thing we love to help with.

Comment: You could also go with a proper German pumpernickel bread (or American knock-off). But I've got to agree with Jolenealaska, that's going to be a really assertive stuffing. The point is to soak up and complement the turkey flavor, not to overpower it entirely... (Also, much easier to cook stuffing not inside a turkey).

Comment: @derobert I might do the German Pumpernickel, because my family is German.  Pumpernickel is not a sourdough though, is it? I want something that will absorb the turkey flavour, keep its form, without adding so much of its own flavour.

Comment: Almost all breads were originally sourdough, pumpernickel can be either nowadays. "extremely brown, super multi-whole-grain" is going to be flavorful (unless you pick some rather boring grains and make it brown with food coloring).

Comment: @Akiva if you don't want assertive flavor, you don't want Russian black bread or pumpernickel. Perhaps a marbled rye? http://redstaryeast.com/marbled-rye-bread/

Comment: Just because one recipe for stuffing made of Wonderbread was bad doesn't mean that **all** stuffings like this are. Not Wonderbread, but my dad uses Pepperidge Farm's thin-sliced white bread and it's a wonderful result... you have to know how to prepare it, though. It's also really not a good idea to actually stuff your raw turkey with raw stuffing and try to get it to bake properly, which is what you seem to be implying you're going to do.

Comment: "super multi-whole-grain", "dry" and "does not crumble" are a bit of antipodes in bread, actually. Whole grain crumbles much more than whiter breads. And it keeps moister.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any bread can be dry - slice or cube and put it in the oven at 140F, or low, until it's as dry as you like.

Wonderbread is not even bread, in my opinion - it's certainly not anything like a yeast bread, even one made from all white flour. So it's not hard to be **very** different from it. As such you might want to heed the advice in comments to scale back your reaction a tad.

For a different approach to "very brown bread" look at Anadama recipies - much of the brown there can be from the molasses, but you can also whole-grain it up as much as you like - but 100% whole grain and some tendency to crumble go together in my experience, so I'd probably limit the whole grains to 25-50% of the flour bill, tops. I quite happily mix and match the whole grains as well as bean flours, potato flour, etc.

Comment: I'm thinking of trying Kartoffelbrot; it should go good with sausages and rosemary. That is good to know that I can just dry it out if I find it too moist.